# Adding an horizontal line in excel graph at the origin of secondary axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following graph in excel, and I would like to add a single line at the level of the zero on the secondary axis

[image]

I thought choosing "horizontal axis cuts on axis=0" in "format axis" options would do it but it seems to have no impact.
I'm starting to suspect this is one of the many flaws of post-2007 Excel graphs design. Is there a way I can add this single horizontal line at the zero level with Excel 2013 ?

Edit : For the avoidance of all doubt, this graph is updating, so I would need the line to move along with the zero on the right axis.

I could draw manually a line but it wouldn't feel very satisfying

Comment: What have you researched to add a target line to your chart? Have you tried `Insert > Shapes` then draw a line on the chart?

Comment: Have you tried adding a series graphed on the secondary axis and whose values are all zero? Format it to a thin black line and you're done.

Comment: @CharlieRB This does not solve my problem as any update in the graph could put this manually drawn line out of zero.

Comment: @EngineerToast It's a workaround that works, but I still wonder why the  "horizontal axis cuts on axis=0"  doesn't do anything

Comment: Well, it was a suggestion based on what you said; "*Is there a way I can add this single horizontal line*". You need to add any specific requirements for a solution to your question. Otherwise, we have no idea what you expect. FWIW, I have used this, and the suggestion from Engineer Toast, with great results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you: Add a secondary horizontal axis.

The axis setting "Horizontal axis crosses" for the primary vertical axis only affects the primary horizontal axis. The setting for the secondary vertical axis only affects the secondary horizontal axis. It doesn't look like you *need* a secondary horizontal axis in this case so you can turn it on, set its crossing point to `0`, and then hide the labels and tick marks.

Example in Original Condition:

[image: Step 1]

(Chart Tools) Design > Add Chart Element > Axes > Secondary Horizontal

[image: Step 2]

Format Secondary Vertical Axis > Axis Options > Horizontal Axis Crosses > Axis Value = 0

[image: Step 3]

Format Secondary Horizontal Axis > Labels = None, Tick Marks = None, Lines = Black Solid 3.0pt Dashed

[image: Step 4]

Comment: Perfect, now it all makes sense : the horizontal axis will only cut at zero if it's visible.